# Django admin render callables in object details page

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Is there any way to render a `callable` method, defined for model, in the admin site except using custom templates? Something similar to the way one can do in list_display.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704239/django-admin-render-callables-in-object-details-page - The close popup is broken in iPad so I can't vote to close it.

Comment: network problem...got submitted twice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - in Django 1.2+, you can use [`readonly_fields`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields), which works in exactly the same way as `list_display`.